# Where to put database initialisation code in Maui App

Tags: c#, .net-core, maui, sqlite-net

I have created a .net standard class library service for accessing a sqlite database in my new Maui app. My question is where to call the initialisation code. I've added the DI registration in `MauiProgram.cs` which registers my `DbService` as the implementation of `IDbService` interface:

```
builder
    .Services
        .AddSingleton<IDbService>(serviceProvider => 
            ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<DbService>(serviceProvider, databasePath))
        .AddSingleton<MainViewModel>()
        .AddSingleton<MainPage>();
```

The code to initialise the database (create tables, load test data) I've currently put in the constructor for the main page viewmodel which is registered as a singleton so the initialisation will only occur once. But obviously calling async initialisation code in the constructor is just wrong. Where is the correct location for this?

```
Task.Run(async () =>
{
    await _dbService.Initialise();
    if (!(await _dbService.GetExperiences(1, 0)).Any())
        await _dbService.LoadTestData();
    await GetData();
}).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Comment: Please understand that .NET applications can be decompiled in 2 clicks. Client-side .NET applications cannot contain sensitive information in code/resource files

Comment: Hmm, not sure where you're going with this. I have a class library `DbService` that provides repo-ish access to a local sqlite database. I'm just looking for the right location in the app code to initialise it. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Well, I mean your maui app should communicate to an api, and not directly connect your database. If you use this class library in your maui app, anyone who has the app installed can easily decompile the dll from your library, and see your database credentials in plaintext

Comment: Just check out what JustDecompile and DotPeek do...

Comment: @Pieterjan that's generally true. Mobile apps should not directly connect to a server database. But they can have local databases. Imagine a clock app, it doesn't need to store your alarms in a server database. Storing in a local database is enough. Even if a user decompiles the app to access the local database, there is no harm. They can only see their own alarms.

Answer (score 5):

For custom startup logic, usually [hosted services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0) are the way to go. But MAUI [does not currently support](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/2244) hosted services. However, there is an [undocumented `IMauiInitializeService`](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/c1525fad1af4ff32aa7abe00119be94f7399d98f/src/Core/src/Hosting/IMauiInitializeService.cs) interface that can be used to implement initialization logic.

```cs
internal class DatabaseInitializer : IMauiInitializeService
{
    public void Initialize(IServiceProvider services)
    {
        var dbService = services.GetRequiredService<IDbService>();
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await dbService.Initialise();
            if (!(await dbService.GetExperiences(1, 0)).Any())
                await dbService.LoadTestData();
            await GetData();
        }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
}
```

This class needs to be registered as an implementation of `IMauiInitiailizeService`:

```cs
builder.Services;
        .AddSingleton<IDbService>(serviceProvider => 
            ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<DbService>(serviceProvider, databasePath))
        .AddSingleton<MainViewModel>()
        .AddSingleton<MainPage>()
        .AddTransient<IMauiInitializeService, DatabaseInitializer>();
```

It will be executed after the application is built, [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/c1525fad1af4ff32aa7abe00119be94f7399d98f/src/Core/src/Hosting/MauiAppBuilder.cs#L164).

It should work by the looks of things. Currently, I don't have MAUI installed so I can't verify for sure. Please let me know if there is a problem.

Comment: `IMauiInitializeService` is not documented for a reason. The author considered it a temporary solution, so it will be removed/ replaced in the future ([source](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/2244)).

Comment: @JHBonarius eventually it will be replaced by hosted services. Until then, this is the cleanest DRY solution.

Comment: I'm thinking of using the `ImplementationFactory` version of `AddSingleton()`. At least then it's all in plain sight and I can wait for hosted services while not relying on functionality that will break in a future release.

Comment: @DavidClarke That's viable. Just don't forget to resolve the singleton after the `MauiApp` is built or else the factory won't get invoked. Alternatively, you can register an initializer service normally and call its `Initalize` method on an instance resolved from `mauiApp.Services` before returining from `CreateMauiApp`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a MAUI beginner so apologies if this is not best practice/helpful.

My MAUI app is set up with a local SQLite DB using EF Core code first migrations.

In App.xaml.cs, I'm using the service provider to create a new scope that gets the DB context. The DB context then applies migrations and adds seed/test data etc.

The following seems to work for me, perhaps you could do something similar using your dbService in place of the ctx...

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    public App(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;

        AddTestData().Wait();

        MainPage = new AppShell();
    }

    public async Task AddTestData()
    {
        using(var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
        {
            await using var ctx = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>();

            await ctx.Database.MigrateAsync();

            // Use ctx to add test/seed data etc

            await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As indicated in the question, calling async code in a constructor is not good practice ref: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html which is why I was looking for an alternative approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static class MauiProgram
    {
        public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
        {
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
           
            builder
                .UseMauiApp<App>()
                .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                {
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                });

            var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json", true, true);

            IConfiguration configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();

            var sqlServerConnectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
            builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer(sqlServerConnectionString));
          
#if DEBUG
        builder.Services.AddBlazorWebViewDeveloperTools();
#endif

            builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();

            // Update Databases when app started
            using (ServiceProvider serviceProvider = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider())
            {
                AppDbContext dbContext = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();

                dbContext.Database.Migrate();
            }

            return builder.Build();
        }
    }
```